# Resuming Training of CNN from checkpoint in torch7

Tags: lua, neural-network, conv-neural-network, torch, checkpoint

I am training a CNN. I achieved about 0.001 l2 loss towards the end of the total epochs and saved a checkpoint. Now, when I wish to resume training, I load the checkpoint and the error I am starting with is greater than 0.008.

Here is how I am saving checkpoints:

```
paths.mkdir('checkpointsR3')
parametersR, gradParametersR = nil, nil -- nil them to avoid spiking memory
if epoch % 50 == 0 then
     util.save('checkpointsR3/' .. opt.name .. '_' .. (epoch+1000) .. '_net_R.t7', netR, opt.gpu)
end
```

Here is how I am loading a checkpoint:

```
-- load Residual Learner
assert(opt.net ~= '', 'provide a generator model')
netR = util.load(opt.net, opt.gpu)
netR:evaluate()
```

The util is a lua file directly used from [soumith chintala's dcgan.torch](https://github.com/soumith/dcgan.torch).

I wish to know where I am going wrong and why is the l2 loss higher than it was when I trained it at that checkpoint. I checked I am loading the most trained checkpoint but still I am getting a higher error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. 
It was a fault in:

```
netR:evaluate()
```

The torch documentation here, [Documentation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md), states that if one wants to resume training, `training()` should be used instead of `evaluate()` because it initializes `BatchNormalization` layers differently for training and testing.